# how to add fallback intent in chatbot just like api.ai

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, chatbot

I am developing a chat bot in Python. I have a data set for 4 intents. I have managed to build a classifier using tfidf and sklearn library to classify the input text in one of 4 trained intents.

But, I want to add another intent i.e if user asks anything out of those 4 intents it should return fallback intent like it does in api.ai

Now when I predict the intent of any rubbish text it always returns "intent no.2".

Answer (score 1):

I think it is one of biggest problems when you are building your own classifier - it always tries to map user input to one of possible intents - do you have any parameter which tells you something about confidence level? If so you could do as follows

```
[response, confidence] = get_intent(user_input)
if (confidence > 0.6):
    print response
else:
    print "Sorry, but I didn't understand your request"
```

Comment: I don't have class probabilities. Model returns the class name.